# Sonar Runner Execution Error

Tags: c#, jenkins, sonarqube

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to fix this error I'm getting with the Sonar Runner on the Jenkins build server.  It's worked fine for me up until today.  I haven't changed any settings or files.  Does anyone know what I need to do to get this running again?

> ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
>   org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
>       at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:79)
>       at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:63)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:57)
>       at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
>       at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:71)
>       at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:89)
>       at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
>       at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
>       at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:41)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown': sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectName, sonar.projectVersion
>       at org.sonar.runner.batch.ProjectReactorBuilder.checkMandatoryProperties(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:314)
>       at org.sonar.runner.batch.ProjectReactorBuilder.defineProject(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:130)
>       at org.sonar.runner.batch.ProjectReactorBuilder.build(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:118)
>       at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.createBatch(IsolatedLauncher.java:60)
>       at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:45)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:75)
>       ... 9 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's due to your `sonar-project.properties` file. It is located at the root of your project. Check if it contains enough (mandatory) information, like, in your case:

- sonar.projectKey
- sonar.projectName
- sonar.projectVersion

Your can find more help [on the documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I checked the sonar-project.properties file and it did not contain that information.  However, I do specify the information in the Jenkins job configuration for Sonar.  I'm using the same sonar runner for several projects and have not had any issues with it until now.

Comment: Yes, you're right, there are two possibilities to perform this. One of the two take precedence over the other. If it has helped you, don't hesitate to validate the answer ;)